# I can't stop walking in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This problem started yesterday.  I was playing minecraft and when I was walking, but after I let go of the W key I kept walking for 4 more seconds.

The same thing happens when I walk backwards.  If I try to jump while walking, the jump is delayed.  I already tried rebooting minecraft, but no luck.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using the PC or pocket version?

Comment: I'm using a pc to play

Comment: Does this happen in any other games, or only Minecraft?

Comment: only just minecraft

Comment: Does this happen with any other tasks in MC? When you open a chest for example, does it also take ~4 seconds?

Comment: I have seen this happen in Minecraft when the computer's processor is heavily loaded. Do you have other things running in the background? Do you use a  lot of mods? Have you updated Minecraft recently, or added new mods?

Comment: actually i did add new mods... it happened when i added new mods and deleted others one... and it only happens when i move around and such

Answer (score 2):

The size of mods can vary, which will effect lag depending on the specs of your PC.

The new mod you have
could be massive , or shaders and OptiFine can also slow your PC down a lot.